# How to interrupt a Timer to Change position along a Colour Cycle

Tags: led, interrupt, timers

I want to have a loop of 4 colours which runs constantly (i.e. red -> green -> blue -> white) each of the colours having their own LED and pin on the Arduino board. There is a 7 second delay between switching the colour and this cycle should run continuously. When I press a button, I want the cycle to immediately switch back to green and continue the cycle (i.e. -> blue -> white -> red) again.

How should I go about this? Can you have a listener for a button press going at the same time as a delay? How do you interrupt the timer and change the active LED?

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the [attachInterrupt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt) example sketch and work from there. Here is a possible solution:

```
enum { GREEN = 0, BLUE = 1, WHITE = 2, RED = 3};
const int buttonPin = 2;
const int ledPin[] = { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
volatile bool reset = false;
int state = GREEN;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) pinMode(ledPin[i], OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPin), doResetState, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
   digitalWrite(ledPin[state], HIGH);
   delay(7000);
   digitalWrite(ledPin[state], LOW);
   if (state == RED || reset) {
     state = GREEN;
     reset = false;
   }
   else {
     state = state + 1;
   }
}

void doResetState () {
    reset = true;
}
```

This will not immediately cycle back to GREEN when pressing the button but you can fix that by modifying the doResetState().

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleTimer library would be ideal for this. One timer callback function, the present contents of the loop() function, would advance the lighting state, called by a 7 second timer. Another, your present doResetState() with the modification noted by @MikaelPatel, would read (and debounce) the button on, say, a 100ms timer. The main loop would be reduced to `Timer.run();`